# Different scopes than I requested with requests_oauthlib in Microsoft Graph

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, requests-oauthlib

I am creating a Python script to use Microsoft Graph API services using the requests_oauthlib library. I am able to create successfully an OAuth2.0 session, get an authorization URL to open in an internet browser window to authenticate, and then I am redirected to the redirect URL that I previously indicated when I registered my app in the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com). Then I copy the full redirect URL to paste into my application. At that point, my app reads the URL that I pasted, exchanges the authentication code that is embedded in the URL for an OAuth authentication token that is perfectly valid. To make sure, I check it in https://jwt.ms, and it is perfect except for the scopes granted. These scopes do not match the scopes that I requested in my OAuth session.

**SCRIPT CODE**

```
# details from the library can be found at https://pypi.org/project/requests-oauthlib/
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session 

client_id = <the client id from the Azure Portal when I registered my app>
client_secret = <the client secret I got from the Azure Portal>
redirect_uri = <the redirect_uri that I specified in the Azure Portal>
authorization_base_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my tenant code>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
token_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my tenant code>/oauth2/v2.0/token'
scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read", "https://graph.microsoft.com/offline_access"]

# OAuth2.0 Authentication
msgraph = OAuth2Session(client_id, scope = scopes, redirect_uri=redirect_uri) # creates a OAuth 2.0 session object

# Redirect user to microsoft for authorization
# offline for refresh token
# force to always make user click authorize
authorization_url, state = msgraph.authorization_url(authorization_base_url, access_type="offline", prompt="select_account")

print('Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url) # user needs to click on this URL, authenticate and copy the URL that will be given

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here: ') # the user has to paste the url with the authorizaton code provided after authenticating
print('redirect_response: ', redirect_response)

# Fetches the access token AFTER the authentication code was given in the previous step
token = msgraph.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret, authorization_response=redirect_response) # gets the access token
print('token: ', token)
```

but I get the following warning message:

> Warning: Scope has changed from "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/offline_access" to "profile https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read openid email".

**API PERMISSIONS IN AZURE PORTAL**

Microsoft Graph (2)
Files.ReadWrite.All
offline_access

As you can see in the Azure permissions above, the privileges (scopes) in the Azure portal are exactly the same scopes that I requested, so my question is where did these '*openid*' and '*email*' scopes come from? I have been able to overcome the warning message, but I can't request the privileges that I need. I even created a brand new application in the Azure portal, but I have the same problem. Is there something wrong with the **requests_oauthlib** library or I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When requesting scopes, you don't need a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) for Graph scopes (they're the default) and you *shouldn't* use them for non-Graph scopes (`openid`, `profile`, `email`, and `offline_access` are OpenID/AAD scopes, not Graph).

```py
scopes = ["User.Read", "offline_access"]
```

Comment: Thank you, Marc. I didn't know about the FQDN part. About the scopes, I am including the offline_access scope for Microsoft login to grant me an OAuth token with a refresh token. The other scopes that you mention (openid, profile & email), I did not ask for them. That is precisely my problem. I don't know who or why they are added. The library requests_oauthlib seems not to follow my instructions or I am doing wrong that creates these "random scopes" to be granted for my token request.

Comment: They're not really random, they're just the Open ID Connect equivalents of `User.Read`. It shouldn't affect how you use the token (or provide any additional access you didn't already ask for).

Comment: Correct. I realized that they just "accumulate" as I request more privileges. Case closed. Thank you!